# IIS 500.51 error and how to fix it

Tags: iis

I've borked my server, and I'm not sure how to fix it. I've cleared my rules, I've reset my web.config back to its pre-rewrite rule state, and still, the error I get is `HTTP Error 500.51 - URL Rewrite Module Error.` So it's obviously that problem, but I don't know what else to do about it. I looked up this error on google, and found that there's a similar one (50), but it doesn't say exactly what I need to do...it seems that it's stuck somewhere, but I have no idea where that would be...How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you re-installed the URL Rewrite Module? Have you checked in the Windows event logs for more information - if there is any?

Comment: Well, I installed it for the first time, rather. And I'm a newbie at Windows, so going to check the logs based on your suggestion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it would seem that IIS had a rule, but wasn't displaying it. I found this out because I restarted IIS entirely, and the rule popped up, and then I was able to delete it, and voila! Back in business.